# Backwards Compatibility on the Tor Network

Tags: onion-services

How big of an issue is backwards compatibility on the Tor network?

The reason I ask is that my Onion v3 hidden service is set up and ready to go, however I am unsure when to discontinue my Onion v2 service.

Do most people use a fully up-to-date Tor browser or is it common for ancient versions to be used?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tor Browser auto updates so all users *should* be on the latest version. Tor Browser updates are *normally* accompanied by at least one security fix, so no one should ever be running old versions of Tor Browser.

However since the current stable Tor Browser only ships with Tor 0.3.1.x and >=0.3.2.x (the current alpha series) is required to use v3 onion services, no one except those using the Tor Browser alpha series (currently 7.5a9) will be able to access v3 onions.

I wouldn't migrate until the stable Tor Browser release is shipping a version of Tor >=0.3.2.x. There is no reason that you cannot run both services at the same time though.

Comment: Ah yes that's what I am doing currently, I have them both running at the same time (on separate servers though). Looks like I'll disable the old one once 0.3.2 has been shipped for a while. Thank you.